# Copy File and create Hyperlink with dynamic foldername

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am setting up a database where projects can have certain attachments. 
Mostly PDFs.

Nice to know:

- Frontend Access
- Backend MySQL
- ODBC Connection

My aim is, to use an attachment field to get the file. And then export this file to a generated folder on a network storage. After exporting the file successfully the attachment gets deleted and a hyperlink has been created.

[image: visualization of my Forn]
With generated folder I mean this:
f.e. a project is called "Constructionsite_A" and the export creates this

C:\Constructionsites\ **Constructionsite_A**
All related PDF are landing in this folder.

This code is generating a specific folder with the correct name(Construction Site A/B/c etc.) If the folder already exists, its just pasting more files into it. So the **export feature is working!**

```
Public Sub AttachmentToDisk(strTableName As String, _
        strAttachmentField As String, strPrimaryKeyFieldName As String)

    Dim strFileName As String

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsParent As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim rsChild As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim fld As DAO.Field2

    Dim strPath As String

    strPath = SpecialFolderPath("Desktop") & "\"

    Set db = CurrentDb

    Set rsParent = db.OpenRecordset(strTableName, dbOpenSnapshot)

    With rsParent
        If .RecordCount > 0 Then .MoveFirst

        While Not .EOF
            ' our picture is in the field "pics"
            Set rsChild = rsParent(strAttachmentField).Value

            If rsChild.RecordCount > 0 Then rsChild.MoveFirst

            While Not rsChild.EOF

                ' this is the actual image content
                Set fld = rsChild("FileData")

                ' create full path and filename
                strFileName = strPath & .Fields(strPrimaryKeyFieldName) & "\" & rsChild("FileName")

               ' take variable to create Path to given textbox
                 Forms![Formular1]![Hyperlink] = strFileName 

                ' create directory if it does not exists
                If Len(Dir(strPath & .Fields(strPrimaryKeyFieldName), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then VBA.MkDir strPath & .Fields(strPrimaryKeyFieldName)
                ' remove any previous picture from disk it there is any
                If Len(Dir(strFileName)) <> 0 Then Kill strFileName

                ' save our picture to disk
                fld.SaveToFile strFileName

                ' move to next attachment
                rsChild.MoveNext
            Wend

            ' move record pointer of parent
            .MoveNext
        Wend

    End With


    Set fld = Nothing
    Set rsChild = Nothing
    Set rsParent = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

> Forms![Formular1]![Hyperlink] = strFileName

- This is getting me a hyperlink to a given Tetxbox named *Hyperlink*
  But its static and can just paste One Hyperlink into it. -> When entering some file at PDF_B the Modul will try to paste the link into the first Textbox ofc. I dont have any idea of fixing this to be kind of dynamic.

The click event at Button " Export and Create Link" is

```
Private Sub Befehl3_Click()
Me.Hyperlink = Null ' Reset textbox
Call AttachmentToDisk("tbl_AuftragsDaten", "testpdf", "KostenstellenZahl")
End Sub
```

Following the code of "Delete Attachment"

- This Button is for **testing.**
- If the "delete code" works I want to **Export, Create Link and Delete Attachment with one click**, so I just need one Attachment field in my table and not 3 ( for PDF_A/B/C )

```
Private Sub Befehl12_Click()
On Error GoTo err_proc
Dim strSQL As String
Dim intPic As Integer
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    Me.Refresh        'New line
    Me.Attachment1.Requery        'New line ' Attachment1 = attachmentbox in form
    intPic = Me.Attachment1.CurrentAttachment
'  Instantiate the parent recordset.
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst1 As DAO.Recordset, rst2 As DAO.Recordset

    ' testpdf = Name of table field for Attachments in tbl_AuftragsDaten. Primary Key= KostenstellenID
    strSQL = "SELECT testpdf FROM tbl_AuftragsDaten WHERE KostenstellenID=" & Me.Text8

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)
    Set rst1 = qdf.OpenRecordset
    If rst1.EOF = True Then GoTo exit_proc
    rst1.MoveFirst
    rst1.Edit
   ' Instantiate the child recordset.

    Set rst2 = rst1.Fields("Attachment1").Value
    rst2.OpenRecordset
    If rst2.EOF = True Then GoTo exit_proc
    rst2.MoveFirst
    If intPic > 0 Then rst2.Move intPic
    rst2.Delete
   ' Update the parent record
    rst1.Update

    Me.Attachment1.Requery
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
exit_proc:
On Error Resume Next
    rst2.Close
    rst1.Close
    qdf.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
err_proc:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume exit_proc
End Sub
```

Normally it should delete the Attachment but I get following error

> Run Time Error 3265 - Item not found in this collection

Tried Error Handling with this code, but I dont get rid of the Error...

```
    Select Case Err.Number
      Case 3265
        Resume Next
```

## Edit after seeking for another way to solve it

```
Option Explicit
 Option Compare Database


 Public Function FCopy(strTableName As String, _
        strPrimaryKeyFieldName As String) As String

 Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsPK As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim File_Name As String
    Dim FD As FileDialog


     strPath = "C:\Users\Felix\Desktop\Neuer Ordner" & "\"

     Set db = CurrentDb

    Set rsPK = db.OpenRecordset(strTableName, dbOpenSnapshot)

    strFileName = strPath & rsPK.Fields(strPrimaryKeyFieldName) & "\"


   ' Set up the File Dialog. '
   Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    ' FD.InitialFileName = Application.CurrentProject.path
   With fDialog

      ' Allow user to make multiple selections in dialog box '
      .AllowMultiSelect = False

      ' Set the title of the dialog box. '
      .Title = "Please select a file"

      ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.'
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the '
      ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns '
      ' False, the user clicked Cancel. '
      If .Show = True Then
         FCopy = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
      Else
        Exit Function
      End If
   End With

   File_Name = Dir(FCopy)
       ' create directory if it does not exists
     If Len(Dir(strPath & rsPK.Fields(strPrimaryKeyFieldName), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then VBA.MkDir strPath & rsPK.Fields(strPrimaryKeyFieldName)
        FileCopy File_Name, strFileName & File_Name
        Set FD = Nothing


End Function
```

This copies a file to a folder. But the folder is always generated by the 1st PrimaryKey of the table. I dont get it to take the current PrimaryKey of the current Record in my form...

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why two procedures? Why not 1 procedure for extract, delete, save text? Will there be only 1 attachment in each record?

Comment: Do you want the hyperlink string saved into same record attachment removed from?

Comment: Why are you using attachment field to begin with? How do you use it to 'get the file'? From where?

Comment: I devided it into two procedures because of testing reasons. And tbh I dont know how to combine both procedures so I have 2.. yeah its kinda dirty style. 

Yes I want to save the hyperlink string into the same record the attachment was removed from. One Record can have several Hyperlinks to several  files, but always just one file will be attached at once.
I Use the Attachment field to Import the file first through the file explorer.I dont know a method where I dont have to use this. Best would be just copying without the need of deleting the file from the Databse bc it was never in there

Comment: The file will be local and have to be copied to a network folder

Comment: Can use Windows File System Object Dialog to 'grab' a file and copy to another folder location. Review https://analystcave.com/vba-application-filedialog-select-file/ The complication of saving to attachment field is unnecessary. So you need a related child table to save the multiple hyperlinks associated with each primary record.

Comment: What is the code for SpecialFolderPath() function?

Comment: AttachmentToDisk function. From `create full path & file Name` to `save our picture to disk`. Will answer the second last comment later.

Comment: I agree with june7, grabbing the file path and moving it saves you time and resources. I developed an app that has this approach. I don’t even worry about subfolders, I just rename the file to an autonumber and save the original file properties to the db record.

Comment: Edited post at the bottom.

Comment: Nice job coding. Your revised code works for me.

Comment: feel free to upvote the Post if it helped you :P, but I always getting Error 70 - Access denied.    When I fixed this problem ( where someone may can help) I will post an extensive answer to my question.

Comment: I didn't need the code, just saying I tested your exact code (except for the path string of course) and it works without error for me. Correction, had to change variable path_name to path. You should have `Option Explicit` at the top of every module.

Comment: @June7 ,  I am still on it implemeting the "create folder" stuff & I hate recordsets.. I just dont get the right PK when generating a folder. I did an edit in my last Code. You may see the bug?   .. got this Error70 fixed btw

Comment: Recordset opens entire table, code references first record. Why use recordset? There is no loop code. Pass the actual PK instead of field name. Or make this a Sub instead of Function and don't pass anything, If procedure is behind form, can just reference form directly `Me!PK`. Code will no longer be generic but tailored to your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code is getting the folder name form textbox in the form, kills a file in the folder with the same name, copies the file, adds a Hyperlink to a given table and if the Hyperlink is already in the table just gives an info output without adding the same Hyperlink again. The variable "Typ" is an additional Info text for the hyperlink.
Thanks @June7 for giving some tips!
If someone needs english comments let me know

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

 Public Function SelectCopy(Typ As String) As String

    Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim File_Name As String
    Dim FD As FileDialog
    Dim rstHyper As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strPrimaryKeyFieldName As String

      ' Bezeichnung des Ordners
    strPrimaryKeyFieldName = Forms![Formular1]![KostenstellenZahl]

      ' DefaultPath festlegen
     strPath = "C:\Users\Felix\Desktop\Neuer Ordner" & "\"

      ' Datenbank festlegen für späteren RS aufruf
     Set db = CurrentDb

      ' Dynamischer Ordner wird erstellt
    strFileName = strPath & strPrimaryKeyFieldName & "\"  

      ' Initieren des FileDialogs. '
        Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

      ' FD.InitialFileName = Application.CurrentProject.path
       With fDialog

      ' True False MultiAuswahl
      .AllowMultiSelect = False

      ' Titel der Dialogbox. '
      .Title = "Bitte Datei auswählen"

      ' Alle Filter löschen und eigene setzen.'
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      ' Dialogbox zeigen. Wenn .Show methode True, der '
      ' Benutzer hat mind. eine Datei ausgewählt. Wenn .Show methode '
      ' False, wurde abgebrochen. '
      If .Show = True Then
        SelectCopy = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
      Else
        Exit Function
      End If
   End With

   ' Der Ausgeählte Dateiname wird formatiert und gespeichert
   File_Name = Dir(SelectCopy)

       ' Ordner mit den Variablen wird erstellt & vorher formatiert
     If Len(Dir(strPath & strPrimaryKeyFieldName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then VBA.MkDir strPath & strPrimaryKeyFieldName

      ' Wenn Datei mit Namen vorhanden wird sie gelöscht
        Dim strFile  As String: strFile = strFileName & File_Name
        If Len(Dir$(strFile)) > 0 Then Kill strFile

        ' Datei wird kopiert
        FileCopy File_Name, strFileName & File_Name

       ' Tabelle wird geöffnet um Hyperlink hinzuzufügen
       Set rstHyper = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_Hyperlink")

        Dim rstfiltered As DAO.Recordset
        Dim Hyperlink As String

'Hyperlink wird übergeben. Wurde zusammengefasst zwecks Syntax
Hyperlink = strFileName & File_Name

' Tabelle öffnen, prüfen ob Hyperlink mit dem PDFs vorhanden
Set rstfiltered = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_Hyperlink WHERE [Hyperlink] = '" & Hyperlink & "'")

'wenn vorhanden Infomeldung
If Not rstfiltered.EOF Then
  MsgBox "Es gibt bereits eine Datei mit dem gleichem Namen. " _
            & "Bitte den Namen mit einem Datum oder einer zusätzlichen Bezeichnung versehen.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Duplicate Entry"

            ' wenn nicht vorhanden hinzufügen der Variablen
        Else
   rstHyper.AddNew
   rstHyper!HyperName = Typ
   rstHyper!Hyperlink = strFileName & File_Name
   rstHyper!HyperKostenstellenIDRef = Forms![Formular1]![KostenstellenID]
   rstHyper.Update
End If

Set rstfiltered = Nothing

    ' Kann später weg genommen werden No need for this
     Forms![Formular1]![hyperhyper] = strFileName & File_Name
        Set FD = Nothing



End Function
```